# insert into item.innerHTML

Tags: javascript, html

I've got a `div` `remaining`

`remaining.innerHTML = "You have NUMBER remaining SECOND VARIABLE"`

I know I can change innerHTML by just doing `remaining.innerHTML = "new string"` but I'm wondering using Javascript how would I inject a new value for NUMBER into the innerHTML without knowing NUMBER's index or value? However the non-variable contents e.g `You have` and `remaining` are constant.

Comment: You want to concatenate a string? http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_operators.asp

Answer (score 4):

Using string concatenation:

```
var number = 1;
var secondVariable = 2;

remaining.innerHTML = "You have " + number + " remaining " + secondVariable;
// results in "You have 1 remaining 2";
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the **`replace()`** method on the string, to replace your markers by their values.

For example, if you use this portion of code :

```
var str = "You have NUMBER remaining SECOND VARIABLE";
var new_str = str.replace('NUMBER', 150).replace('SECOND VARIABLE', 'plop');
```

The `new_str` variable will have as value :

```
"You have 150 remaining plop"
```

Which, applied to your specific case, would give something such as this :

```
remaining.innerHTML = "You have NUMBER remaining SECOND VARIABLE".replace('NUMBER', 150).replace('SECOND VARIABLE', 'plop');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
remaining.innerHTML = "You have " + var1 + " remaining " + var2;
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
var no1 = 5;
var no2 = 10;
remaining.innerHTML = "You have " + no1 + " remaining " + no2;
```